# Trying to use drawImage() with a webGL HTMLCanvasElement fails and wipes the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, createjs, drawimage

I'm using a small stack of canvases to render a 3d scene with 2d background and UI overlay. I'm trying to provide internal screenshot capability, but while I can capture the 2d canvases correctly, the 3d one doesn't seem to be snapshotting correctly. Specifically, my screenshot code looks like this:

```
screenshotCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(backgroundStage.canvas, 0, 0);
screenshotCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(threedStage.canvas, 0, 0);
screenshotCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(uiStage.canvas, 0, 0);
```

where backgroundStage, threedStage and uiStage are [CreateJS](https://createjs.com/) stages. I've specifically created the context for `threedStage.canvas` with `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` as suggested elsewhere. What's more, when I step through this code in Safari using the canvas debugging tools, I can see that my webGL canvas is fine before the middle `drawImage()` call but empty afterwards, even though that call seems as though it should be nondestructive.

I know that it's not possible to have both a 2d and a webgl context for the same canvas, but I would have thought that just using the canvas with the webgl context as an HTMLCanvasElement to draw out of should work and be nondestructive. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: without a repo we can't tell you why it's not working. Can you put a **minimal** repo in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? Just draw a rectangle in each canvas then draw them all into the screenshot canvas. See [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-smallest-programs.html) for a miinmal webgl program

Comment: Sounds like you faced a [*webglcontextlost*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/webglcontextlost_event).